# Codeigniter image is not cropping

Tags: codeigniter

I tried the following code to crop an image in codeigniter but it did not work. Might be I am missing minute thing. Helper is loaded and the image is also exists
The code is

```
 public function cropAndSave(){
                    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                    $config['source_image'] = './img-lab/xxx.jpg';
                    $config['create_thumb'] = true;
                    $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
                    $config['width'] = 150;
                    $config['height'] = 190;
                    $config['new_image'] = "thumb_shahid.jpg";
                    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                    echo '
                    <script>
                         window.parent.location="'.  base_url().'"
                    </script>
                    ';
}
```

Comment: Some further code/context would be helpful.  For example what are you doing after the !$this->image_lib->crop() check?  I would also imagine that the mypic.jpg wouldn't be the full path to your image.

Comment: have you enabled full logging/debugging? Also what graphics library are you using? It is not defined 'gd2'? etc;  You need that module installed in order to use it, the helper just 'helps' make it easier to do.

Comment: @simnom, have posted full code.

Comment: @Chintoo, how about having GD2 installed on your server?  Is it showing up when you run `<?php php_info(); ?>` in a separate file on your server?

Comment: Yes it is installed. On another page it is resizing successfully

Comment: On another page in the same application it is working for resizing. It means gd is installed and working\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `initialize()` function instead of `load()` because your image library already loaded

```
 public function cropAndSave(){
                        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
                        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                        $config['source_image'] = './img-lab/xxx.jpg';
                        $config['create_thumb'] = true;
                        $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
                        $config['width'] = 150;
                        $config['height'] = 190;
                        $config['new_image'] = "thumb_shahid.jpg";
                        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                        $this->image_lib->resize();
                        echo '
                        <script>
                             window.parent.location="'.  base_url().'"
                        </script>
                        ';
    }
```